# External images in AEM CQ5 component

Tags: aem

I have a image URL which refers to some site.
Is it possible to display this image in a component without downloading this image to DAM.

Thanks in advance,
Mayur

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is simple

```
<img src="http://www.somesite.com/path/to/image/image1.jpg" alt="SImage Alt">
```